# Angular Js Smart Table custom filter to search muti word filter using space

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I am struggling with custom filter directive for past five hours. I am beginner of angularjs.
I have a table with all needs except of filter. i want global multiple string filter using space in a single search text box.
Here is my code :

```
app.filter('multiWordFilter', ['$filter', function ($filter) {

    // function that's invoked each time Angular runs $digest()
    return function (input, predicate) {
        var searchValue = predicate['$'];
        //console.log(searchValue);
        var customPredicate = function (value, index, array) {
            console.log(value);
            // alert(searchValue);

            // if filter has no value, return true for each element of the input array
            if (typeof searchValue === 'undefined') {
                return true;
            }
            var propList = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(value) || [];
            var splitValue = (searchValue || '').split(' ');
            var resultArray = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < propList.length; i++) {
                var prop = propList[i];
                if (typeof value[prop] !== 'string')
                    continue;

                for (var j = 0; j < splitValue.length; j++) {
                    var searchText = splitValue[j];
                    if (!searchText)
                        continue;

                    var index = (String)(value[prop]).toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase());
                    if (index > -1) {
                        trueList.push(true);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return trueList.length
        }
        return $filter('filter')(input, customPredicate, false);
    }
}])
```

above code working only for single string search and also i try to get multiple string split with space
for ex
|Name|ContactNo|
|:Asraf|8765270810|
|:Ram|8765270810|

search word be like **8754270810 Asraf**

only return first search result not a second.

I am expecting

search word be like **8754270810** will return two records
search word be like **8754270810 Asraf** will return one record

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Try this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19405684/5781575

Comment: @tbone849 Thanks for your comment, but possibly not working with multiple properties as well as multiple word sperated by space in single row search.

Comment: Hmm. Give this a look. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31370761/5781575

Comment: @tbone849, Thank you so much, small change in my code to achieve what i am expecting.
just use of searchCount thats equal to split value count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an solution for above my problem.

```
app.filter('multiWordFilter', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    // function that's invoked each time Angular runs $digest()
    return function (input, predicate) {
        var searchValue = predicate['$'];
        var customPredicate = function (value, index, array) {

            // if filter has no value, return true for each element of the input array
            if (typeof searchValue === 'undefined') {
                return true;
            }
            var propList = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(value) || [];
            var splitValue = ((String)(searchValue).trim() || '').split(' ');

            if (!splitValue.length)
                return true;

            var searchCount = 0;
            for (var j = 0; j < splitValue.length; j++) {
                var searchText = splitValue[j];
                if (!searchText)
                    continue;
                for (var i = 0; i < propList.length; i++) {
                    var prop = propList[i];
                    if (typeof value[prop] !== 'string')
                        continue;

                    var index = (String)(value[prop]).toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase());
                    if (index > -1) {
                        searchCount++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return (searchCount == splitValue.length)
        }
        return $filter('filter')(input, customPredicate, false);
    }
}])
```

Here when split Search Text value count and searched count is equal then only the matched records available there.

In my case assume a grid has 10 rows, Search Text is : 'Dog eat'.
Now what will actually happen there is, first filter with **Dog** now we have 7 rows and then now filter with **eat** in previous filter where already we get 7 rows, finally we get 4 rows. this is the output what actually i want.

Thank u guys who spend your precious time for my question.